# Is "LIMIT 1" recommended  for query where WHERE condition is based on PK?

Tags: mysql, limit

I am querying a mySQL database to retrieve the data from 1 particular row.  I'm using the table primary key as the WHERE constraint parameter.

E.g.

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE userid = 4
```

The userid column is the primary key of the table.  Is it good practice to use LIMIT 1 on the end of that mySQL statement?  Or are there any speed benefits?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would call that a bad practice as when it comes to something like a `userid` it's generally unique and you won't have more than one. Therefore, having `LIMIT 1` seems pretty contradictory and someone who comes to maintain your code later may have to second-guess your design.

Also, I don't think it has any speed benefit at all. You can check out mySQL's [Explain](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) for a simple tool to analyze a query.

Note, as mentioned in the comments. `LIMIT #` does have speed and general benefits in other cases, just not this one.

Comment: Haha thanks.  Maybe I should change it to "worst practices" :)  I guess mostly I was curious about the speed benefits.  Which it sounds like it doesn't have any.

Comment: @justinl:  to be sure, "LIMIT n" does not offer any speed benefit _in this case_ (of PK-based criteria) however in many other cases, it is a significant factor of performance improvement.  I concur that using it here would be an `unfortunate practice` (certainly _not_ the "worst", I'm afraid !!!)

Answer (score 15):

> The userid column is the primary key of the table. Is it good practice to use LIMIT 1 on the end of that mySQL statement? Or are there any speed benefits?

It is not good practice to use `LIMIT 1` at the end of the example - it's completely unnecessary, because the userid column is a primary key.  A primary key means there is only one row/record in the table with that value, only one row/record will ever be returned.

But the ultimate indicator is the explain plan:

```
explain SELECT t.name FROM USERS t WHERE t.userid = 4
```

...returns:

```
id  | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys  | key      | key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | SIMPLE      | users   | const | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY  | 4        | const | 1      |
```

...and:

```
explain SELECT t.name FROM USERS t WHERE t.userid = 4 LIMIT 1
```

...returns:

```
id  | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys  | key      | key_len  |  ref  |  rows  |  Extra
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | SIMPLE      | users   | const | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY  | 4        | const | 1      |
```

### Conclusion

No difference, no need.  It appears to be optimized out in this case (only searching against the primary key).

### The LIMIT clause

Using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` will return an arbitrary row/record if more than one is returned.  For example, using the "John Smith" scenario where 2+ people can have the name "John Smith":

```
SELECT t.userid
  FROM USERS t
 WHERE t.first_name = 'John'
   AND t.last_name = 'Smith'
 LIMIT 1
```

...risks returning any of the possible `userid` values where the first name is "John" and the last name is "Smith".  It can't be guaranteed to always return the same value, and the likelihood of getting a different value every time increases with the number of possible records.

Personally I don't care for the use of LIMIT.  The syntax isn't supported on Oracle, SQL Server or DB2 - making queries less portable.  LIMIT is a tool to be used conservatively, not the first thing you reach for - know when to use aggregate and/or analytic functions.

Comment: +1: Good explanation, and good point about portability.  (The useless LIMIT would actually give you an imperceptible decrease in performance.)

Comment: Hey this is great!  Thank you for going so far in depth